# Макрос на копирование диапозона значений по дням в Excel

Tags: excel

Нужно,чтобы значения из С15:С20 переносились по кнопке макроса в определенные столбцы таблицы D14:AI20.Столбец определяется датой,которая записывается в ячейке C1.
И самое главное,что эти значения должны оставаться в этой таблице,когда будет сменяться дата и макрос будет выполняться относительно уже новой даты.К концу месяца вся таблица должна быть заполненной.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nvzv7Piz1AesQXt9XckE6AlzRMEmeDvp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: В `C15:C20` - сумма из верхней таблицы? В верхней таблице может быть  больше записей? Тогда нужно определять диапазон суммирования... Лучше перенести суммы иэ `C15:C20` в диапзон, не зависящий от количества записей в таблице. И пример желательно в файле показать. Мало удовольствия в том, чтобы создавать новую книгу и переносить в нее данные из рисунка.

Comment: А ответ на вопрос? *В верхней таблице может быть больше записей?... Лучше перенести суммы иэ C15:C20 в диапзон, не зависящий от количества записей в таблице*

Comment: я сделал видимыми те расчеты,которые ведут к тем результатам,которые указываются вС15:С20.Так как таблицей буду пользоваться другие,я предварительно эти процессы скрыл,но сейчас для понимая снова сделал их видимыми(все значения серого цвета).

костыли конечно,но и я не программист.Поэтому обращаюсь к вам)

Comment: Третий раз! *В верхней таблице может быть больше записей?*..Ведь если таблица может расширяться вниз, сместится ниже и диапазон сумм...

Comment: нет,там конечное число записей,если речь идет о таблице с часами(10:00-20:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать примерно так. Затем функцию назначить на какую-нибудь нарисованную кнопку

```
function writeIt() {
  var arr = {
    '1': 'E', '2': 'F', '3': 'G', '4': 'H', '5': 'I',
    '6': 'J', '7': 'K', '8': 'L', '9': 'M', '10': 'N',
    '11': 'O', '12': 'P', '13': 'Q', '14': 'R', '15': 'S',
    '16': 'T', '17': 'U', '18': 'V', '19': 'W', '20': 'X',
    '21': 'Y', '22': 'Z', '23': 'AA', '24': 'AB', '25': 'AC',
    '26': 'AD', '27': 'AE', '28': 'AF', '29': 'AG', '30': 'AH',
    '31': 'AI'
  }
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet_id");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('List1');
  var current_date = sheet.getRange('C1').getValue();
  var cellsValues = sheet.getRange('C15:C20').getValues();
  sheet.getRange(arr[current_date]+"15:"+arr[current_date]+"20").setValues(cellsValues);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Макрос на `VBA`. Код разместить в общем модуле. На кнопку повесить выполнение макроса.

```
Sub RecordDay()
    Dim j As Long
    
    If MsgBox("Записать данные за указванное число?", 64 + vbYesNo, "СОХРАНЕНИЕ") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    j = Range("C1").Value + 5
    Cells(4, j).Resize(6, 1).Value = Range("C18:C23").Value
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Формат `.xlsx` не подерживает макросы, книгу нужно сохранить с расширением `.xlsm`

Таблицу со списком и суммами можно скрыть группировкой. Формула в `C18` (и протянуть ниже):

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($C$5:$C$13;A18)*B18+ЕСЛИ($C$4=A18;B18*0,25)
```